# Como descobrir select sem where em uma aplicacao laravel

Tags: laravel, select, desempenho, where

Pessoal estou com um problema e nao consigo identificar em qual ponto o laravel esta fazendo um select sem where em uma tabela com muitos registros, alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: Já tentou o debug? Vê se ajuda: [link 1](https://scotch.io/tutorials/debugging-queries-in-laravel) e [link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236294/how-do-i-get-the-query-builder-to-output-its-raw-sql-query-as-a-string)

Comment: Entao na verdade eu nao sei nem aonde ela esta sendo executada, temos 3 projetos grandes q acessam um dabase e esta consulta esporadicamente trava o banco. Ja tentei procurar todas as consultas referentes ao model nos 3 projetos mas sem sucesso ate o momento. Alguma sugestao? A consulta tem sql_no_cache do eloquent Obrigado pela sua pronta resposta

Comment: Instala o laravel-debugbar, pode ser que auxilie - https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar